# jQuery conversion onclick to onload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one website link which currently is working when clicking the link a window pop-up, but I want the `onclick` to happen automatically without clicking. The `onclick` should work like `onload`.

I tried a lot of Google and StackOverflow searches.. but I couldn't find the exact solution to my problem.

Here's my code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>mygame | Browser</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../api.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            document.getElementById('robrowser').addEventListener("click", function(){
                var ROConfig = {
                    type:          ROBrowser.TYPE.POPUP,
                    application:   ROBrowser.APP.ONLINE,
                    remoteClient:  "http://play.mygame.com/client",
                    width:          1024,
                    height:         768,
                    development:    false,
                    servers: [{
                        display:     "mygame",
                        desc:        "mygame Revolution",
                        address:     "94.99.190.98",
                        port:        6900,
                        version:     46,
                        langtype:    12,
                        packetver:   20170614,
                        packetKeys:  false,
                        socketProxy: "ws://196.66.646.179:5999/"
                    }],
                    saveFiles:       true,
                    skipServerList:  true,
                    skipIntro:       true,
                    version:         1,
                    plugins: {
                        IntroMessage:  {}
                    }
                };
                var RO = new ROBrowser(ROConfig);
                RO.start();
            }, false );
        }
        window.addEventListener("load", initialize, false);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Run roBrowser" id="robrowser"/>
</body>
```

Comment: So why not just remove the event listener and execute the source code within the event listener inside your `initialize()` function?

Comment: how can I do it, sir? removing the event listener and execute the source code within the event listener ? can you please rewrite it for me, I am a newbie at it.

Comment: It should be as simple as removing the following lines of soce `document.getElementById('robrowser').addEventListener("click", function(){` and `}, false );` Try that and let me know the results. Here is a [**PasteBin**](https://pastebin.com/bzRLGfqx) of the changes I have suggested.

Comment: Is my suggestion of any help or are you still having problems?

Comment: yes sir that worked,thanks a lot for this..
 but the normal click button doesnt work anymore.
is it possible to have both working ?

Comment: That is because you have removed the event listener. You didn't say you want the button to still work. Are you wanting the button to work? If you expect the button to still execute the function you can use this [**PasteBin**](https://pastebin.com/1QeWYjce) Let me know the outcome of trying this one. Thank you.

Comment: I have updated my last [**PasteBin / 1QeWYjce**](https://pastebin.com/1QeWYjce) due to a minor mistake so please ensure you are using the updated like.

Comment: thanks a lot worked well

Comment: I have posted  a solution/answer and included the changes made to your existing source code.

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate a buttonclick like this:

```
$("#robrowser").click();
```

In this case you want to run the method when a page is loaded.
You can just remove the entire onclick listener and call the function initialize() directly:

```
function initialize() {
                var ROConfig = {
                    type:          ROBrowser.TYPE.POPUP,
                    application:   ROBrowser.APP.ONLINE,
                    remoteClient:  "http://play.mygame.com/client",
                    width:          1024,
                    height:         768,
                    development:    false,
                    servers: [{
                        display:     "mygame",
                        desc:        "mygame Revolution",
                        address:     "94.99.190.98",
                        port:        6900,
                        version:     46,
                        langtype:    12,
                        packetver:   20170614,
                        packetKeys:  false,
                        socketProxy: "ws://196.66.646.179:5999/"
                    }],
                    saveFiles:       true,
                    skipServerList:  true,
                    skipIntro:       true,
                    version:         1,
                    plugins: {
                        IntroMessage:  {}
                    }
                };
                var RO = new ROBrowser(ROConfig);
                RO.start();
        }

initialize();
```

Answer (score 1):

The following changes have been made:

1. `button` on click event listener moved into the `window` load function
2. The source code from the `button` click event moved into `initialize()`
3. `button` on click event  to target the function `initialize`
4. `window` load function calls/executes `initialize()`

Source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>mygame | Browser</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../api.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
    var ROConfig = {
        type:          ROBrowser.TYPE.POPUP,
        application:   ROBrowser.APP.ONLINE,
        remoteClient:  "http://play.mygame.com/client",
        width:          1024,
        height:         768,
        development:    false,
        servers: [{
display:     "mygame",
desc:        "mygame Revolution",
address:     "94.99.190.98",
port:        6900,
version:     46,
langtype:    12,
packetver:   20170614,
packetKeys:  false,
socketProxy: "ws://196.66.646.179:5999/"
        }],
        saveFiles:       true,
        skipServerList:  true,
        skipIntro:       true,
        version:         1,
        plugins: {
IntroMessage:  {}
        }
    };
    var RO = new ROBrowser(ROConfig);
    RO.start();      
}

window.addEventListener("load", function(){
document.getElementById('robrowser').addEventListener("click", initialize, false );
initialize();
}, false);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Run roBrowser" id="robrowser"/>
</body>
</html>
```

If you have any questions about the source code above please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps, happy coding!